# How to quickly make a matrix table out of excel data?

Tags: r, excel, matrix

I have an excel file with the following data

[image]

I wish to make a matrix table out of this, one quick way of doing it was manually typing the following code

`table <- matrix(c(292, 289, 299, 333, 253, 260, 260, 284, 262, 326, 120, 108, 120, 116, 106, 102, 114, 127, 130, 155), ncol = 2)`

However, if I have data with 100s of entries, is there a quicker way of doing it?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `as.matrix(df1[-1])` (after reading the data)

Comment: There are various functions in R (`read_excel` in the `readxl` package or `read.xlsx` in the `xlsx` package) that will read your excel file directly or after you save it as a .csv file. Have you tried those?

Comment: readxl, etc. I have used and will only load the file on R. I wanted to convert it to a matrix; Akrun answered my Q really well!